# NullPointerException : Struts 2 redirection with extra parameter

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

**Problem Statement**

I want to send some extra parameters while struts action redirects to a JSP page. If it's one parameter or two which is small in size then i can pass those in the form of query parameter, i.e `Request.jsp?param1=hello`.

**What i have tried**

I checked out [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-configure-static-parameter-for-action-class/) and did accordingly.
This is my `struts.xml` file :

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="100000000" />

<!-- <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/service" /> -->

<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default"
    namespace="/">
<action name="request"
        class="com.ModifyRequest">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">Request.jsp?orderId=123
        </result>
        <result name="failure" type="redirect">Request.jsp?orderId=123
            <param name="failureMessage">${failureMessage}</param>
            <param name="status">${status}</param>
        </result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

And this is my Action class :

```
public class ModifyRequest extends ActionSupport implements Parameterizable{

private Map<String, String> params;

private String failureMessage;
private String status;


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getFailureMessage() {
    return failureMessage;
}

public void setFailureMessage(String failureMessage) {
    this.failureMessage = failureMessage;
}

@Override
public void addParam(String arg0, String arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //params.put(arg0, arg1);

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return params;
}

@Override
public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<String,String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    paramMap.put("failureMessage", "failureMessage"); // temporary value
    paramMap.put("status", "status"); // temporary value
    this.params = paramMap;

}


@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    if(false){
        this.status = "success..";
        this.failureMessage = "success message";
        return SUCCESS;
    } else{

        this.status = "failure";
        this.failureMessage = "failure message..";
        return "failure";
    }

}


}
```

The relevant part of my JSP file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alert('<%=request.getParameter("failureMessage")%>');
alert('<%=request.getParameter("status")%>');

 /*
 // i have written an hidden element setting this value, so i get the desired output.
alert('<%=request.getParameter("userId")%>');
*/


<form action="request" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value= "joshi">
</form>
```

I have not mentioned getter and setter for userId in the Action class, as it was no required, so please ignore that part.

It throws the following exception in browser :

```
Struts Problem Report

 Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

 Messages:  
 File:  org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ServletRedirectResult.java
 Line number:   257
 Stacktraces

 java.lang.NullPointerException

 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult.isPathUrl
 (ServletRedirectResult.java:257)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult.doExecute(ServletRedirectResult.java:177)
```

If i remove `<param> elemnets` from `result` element then it does not throw any exception, but my problem is not solved.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Why are you using Redirect ? Why are you implementing Parametrizable ? Please explain exactly what you want to achieve, it is probably 100 times easier than you think (and 1337 times easier than what you are doing)

Comment: `Request.jsp` must be in its own tag.

Comment: @AndreaLigios i am using redirect because the page as it takes orderId as query parameter and based on that it does many operation before it loads the `request form`. 

Can you please suggest some ways (out of your 1337 ways) to solve. it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joshi, I still don't understand what you are doing here.

It should be simpler: in Struts2, parameters (no matters if from Querystring or Form) are handled through Getters and Setters. You didn't post your JSP so I could not tell if you are doing something strange there, but about the rest:

1. Use the default [`Dispatcher Result`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/dispatcher-result.html) type, not the [`Redirect Result`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/redirect-result.html) type;
2. Use [`ActionMessage`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/ActionMessage.html)s and [`ActionError`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/ActionError.html)s to carry your *feedbacks* from the Action to the JSP page, they're provided by the framework for this reason;
3. If there aren't compelling reasons to do otherwise, use the default results: `"success"` and `"error"`, exposed as constants by the `ActionSupport` class (that you extend);
4. Due to `Intelligent Default`, you can omit the result name for the `"success"` result.

Struts.xml

```
<action name="request" class="com.ModifyRequest">
        <result>Request.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Request.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Action

```
public class ModifyRequest extends ActionSupport{

    private String exampleParameterFromJSP;        

    public String getExampleParameterFromJSP() {
        return exampleParameterFromJSP;
    }
    public void setExampleParameterFromJSP(String exampleParameterFromJSP) {
        this.exampleParameterFromJSP = exampleParameterFromJSP;
    }


    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {    
        if("1337".equals(exampleParameterFromJSP)){
            addActionMessage("SUCCESS !! So long and thanks for all the fish!");
            return SUCCESS;
        } else{                
            addActionError("ERROR !! You must write '1337' to make it works!");
            return ERROR;
        }

    }

}
```

Hypotetical JSP:

```
<s:actionerror />
<s:actionmessage />
<s:form action="request">
    <s:textfield name="exampleParameterFromJSP" />
    <s:submit value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />
</s:form>
```

## EDIT

After you posted your JSP, the *main* problem is now evident:

- Do not use `Scriptlet`s (`<%`, `<%=` ... they are *Old and Bad(tm)*, and run in a different scope);
- Use Struts tags when possible.

```
<form action="request" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value= "joshi">
</form>
```

should be (preferred solution):

```
<s:form action="request" method="post">
  <s:hidden name="userId" />
</s:form>
```

or AT LEAST this:

```
<form action="request" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<s:property value='userId'/>" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks and i appreciate the effort. I have given example of `failureMessage` and `status` as just parameter names, but i want is to send some more details to the redirected page. Those details are not just failure or success message to display. More over those details can not be part of URL, but redirected page requires those. Do you understand me or any more clearance let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely; I changed the name of the parameter to show you that ! Declare all the parameters you want, and read them from the JSP, as long as they have the GETTER. (and set them by submitting the JSP, as long as they have the SETTER). Try that, you will see that you'll have access to Action data from JSP `without anything written in the URL`; JSP and Struts tags are evaluated server side, the client will receive pure HTML... and no redirect are involved here, it is a simple forward

Comment: I tried it and found this. 

If i set the parameters, available in action class, from JSP( of course they have the SETTER), then only i am getting the value of those parameters in the next JSP(i.e dispatched JSP). 

If i don't create those hidden elements having `id` same as those parameters in Action class, then i get `NULL` value, even if i am setting some value in `business logic`. 
So i am stuck where i was.

Comment: Can you post the (relevant part of your) JSP ?

Comment: Have you tried like in my edited answer ? Do you still have problems ?

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition add to answer given by @Andrea, which works fine. Just wanted to provide some extra reference for better understanding.

This was my JSP(as in the question) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alert('<%=request.getParameter("failureMessage")%>');
alert('<%=request.getParameter("status")%>');

<form action="request" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value= "joshi">
</form>
```

Using `request.getParameter()` returns http request parameter which are sent as query parameter, where as `request.getAttribute()` returns value set in server side, i.e servlet.

`request.getParameter()` only returns string object where as `request.getAttribute()` returns an Object, it can be of any type.

An alternate solution to the question is to use `request.getAttribute()` in JSP to get the parameters or proeprties value. No need to implement `Parameterizable` interface in Action class, rather just provide properties and their `getters` and `setters`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alert('<%=request.getAttribute("failureMessage")%>');
alert('<%=request.getAttribute("status")%>');

<form action="request" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value= "joshi">
</form>
```

Thats an added solution to the problem.